# Creating longest line within polygon that crosses point

Tags: qgis, polygon, distance, polyline-creation, maximum

I am performing a morphometric analysis of dolines using QGIS. I want to generate longest axis within basin polygon that crosses the lowest point (from other layer) of basin. Is there a way to generate it?

[image: Illustration of longest axis]

Images taken from Bondensan et al.

Comment: Is there any logical/geometrical connection between the point and the polygon?

Comment: There are an almost infinite number of pairs of lines that can fulfil that requirement

Comment: Maybe it would help to know, if these lines should be aligned N-S and E-W or if they should divide the polygone with a certain percentage of area contained within etc. A clearification would certainly help

Comment: at least one end of your axis will go through a vertex of the polygon. You can find the longest axis by enumerating all the vertices and finding the length of the axis through each vertex, then selecting the longest. You can do this using PyQgis.

Comment: Similar question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/365901/finding-longest-straight-line-within-polygon-in-qgis

Answer (score 6):

Here is an approach using PyQGIS.

It uses the points as startpoint for a bruteforce method to find the longest line inside the intersecting single-polygon. It considers holes in the polygons. You can adjust the quality of the result by modifying the variable `azimuthsteps`, but consider that the lower its value the slower the execution of the code but the better the result.

You can find an explanation below code and demo-gif.

```py
points = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('point')[0]
polygons = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('polygon')[0]
azimuthsteps = 1 # number of trys, the lower the value the slower the performance but the better the result!!
linedist = 1000000 # imaginary maximum line length

vl = QgsVectorLayer("LineString?crs={}&index=yes".format(points.crs().authid()), "Longest_line", "memory")
pr = vl.dataProvider()

polygons_idx = QgsSpatialIndex(polygons.getFeatures()) # spatial index for polygonlayer

with edit(vl):
    for point in points.getFeatures(): # iterate over pointlayer
        for pid in polygons_idx.intersects(point.geometry().boundingBox()): # iterate over intersecting polygons
            intersectingpolygon = polygons.getFeature(pid) # get current intersecting polygon
            linedict = {} # refresh the temporary featid linelength dictionary
            resultlines = [] # list of maximum linelengths id's
            step = 0 # reset the current step
            # create a temporary layer
            tmpvl = QgsVectorLayer("MultiLineString?crs={}&index=yes".format(points.crs().authid()), "tmplines", "memory")
            tmppr = tmpvl.dataProvider()
            for step in range(180,360, azimuthsteps): # iterate in the specified steps over the azimuths from current point
                with edit(tmpvl):
                    tmplinefeat = QgsFeature() # create a feature
                    stepopposite = step - 180 # reverse the azimuth
                    pointpoint = QgsPoint(point.geometry().asPoint()) # make a QgsPoint out of the pointgeometry
                    startpoint = pointpoint.project(linedist,step) # Project a point in the given azimuth (step) from the current point and declare it as startpoint of the line
                    endpoint = pointpoint.project(linedist,stepopposite) # Project a point on the opposite site from the startpoint, so we get a straigt line
                    tmplinefeat.setGeometry(intersectingpolygon.geometry().intersection(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([startpoint, endpoint]))) # create a line inside the polygon
                    tmpvl.addFeature(tmplinefeat) # add the feature
                    tmpvl.updateFeature(tmplinefeat) # update it
            # convert the temporary layer to a singleline-layer
            blubb = processing.run("native:multiparttosingleparts",{'INPUT':tmpvl,'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
            singlelines = blubb['OUTPUT']
            singlelines_idx = QgsSpatialIndex(singlelines.getFeatures()) # spatial index for singlelines
            for slid in singlelines_idx.intersects(point.geometry().boundingBox()): # iterate over features of singlelines that intersect with their point
                slidf = singlelines.getFeature(slid) # get the feature by the id from the index
                linedict[slid] = slidf.geometry().length() # add line's featureid and length to the temporary dictionary
            resultlines.append(max(linedict, key=linedict.get, default=0)) # append the longest line's featureid from the temporary dictionary to the resultlist
            resultfeatures = [] # create an empty list of matching features
            for slf in singlelines.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFids(resultlines)): # iterate over the matching features in templayer
                resultfeatures.append(slf) # append features to resultlist
            pr.addFeatures(resultfeatures) # copy all resultfeatures to final layer
            # remove the temporary layers
            QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayers([tmpvl.id()])
            QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayers([singlelines.id()])
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl) # add the finalized layer to canvas
```

Demo:

[image]

Explanation:

First we build a spatial index on the polygon layer to find intersecting polygons for each point faster.

Now we are iterating over the pointlayer and get all intersecting polygons by using the spatial index. Now we iterate over these polygons, build an empty dictionary where we store the featureid's and linelengths of the lines we are going to generate. Therefore we build a temporary multilinelayer.

Next we build projected points for each point. One startpoint and one endpoint. Therefore we are building a circle of start- and endpoints around each point and connect them by a line. So we get a star of lines, where the point is its center. This is the part where you can control the stars density by adjusting the `azimuthsteps` variable. Then we trim these lines to the point-intersecting polygon. We will now have a couple of multilinestrings.

As we do not want multilines, we need to convert them to singlelines by using the processing algorithm `multiparttosingleparts`. Here we will also get singlelines as output that do not intersect with the point, so we are building a spatial index on the singlelines to test them efficently against an intersection with the point and keep only those that do intersect. Then we add them to the dictionary. Their id as key and their length as value.

Then we find the maximum value/length inside this dictionary and grab the corresponding feature(s), and add these features to the resultfeatures-list. Finally we copy these features to our final outputlayer. At a last step we will then clean up the temporary layers to not spam the project.

Done.

Comment: Thank you sir... it's works to me

Comment: But..when I try to execute the script on polygon layer with each features coincide (create from splitted polygon), the script does'nt work, with error message: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 38, in <module>
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence

Is the script can only be used on layers where each feature separated each other @MrXsquared?

Comment: @Arief This error occurs if the dictionary is empty (or another issue I can not imagine atm) and therefore no max value is available. I just added a default value to fix that in the code. However, this will probably not solve your actual issue which must lay somewhere in your dataset. Maybe an invalid or empty feature is causing this or .... Can only help there if you provide the data. For now, if its really only one feature causing that, it should be skipped by now. Also please consider [upvoting and/or accepting answers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) you find useful.

Comment: On the other hand: could it be that your data is in EPSG:4326 and the polygons very small, so all lines have a distance of 0.0000...001 degree? If so try reprojecting your data to a metric system.

Comment: if you finde an answer helpfull, you may indicate that it solved your problem