# How can I measure the largest diameter of a polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, distance

I am needing to find the largest distance between 2 vertices of a polygon in QGIS.

I am aware I can just use the measuring tool but sometimes I can have over 400 polygons to measure so ideally this would be automated. I assumed since I can automatically measure the area, there would also be a way to measure the diameter.

Comment: Here is a related [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/365901/finding-longest-straight-line-within-polygon-in-qgis) where the largest line should not cross the polygon boundary or inner hole.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a tool called Minimum enclosing circles in the processing toolbox.

> This algorithm calculates the minimum enclosing circle which covers
> each feature in an input layer.
>
> See the 'Minimum bounding geometry'
> algorithm for a minimal enclosing circle calculation which covers the
> whole layer or grouped subsets of features.

Comment: That's perfect thanks! I've used that which provided me a radius. And then used the field calculator to multiply that column by 2 which has given me the info I need. Thanks a lot!