# Creating line inside polygon using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, polyline-creation, within

I do have polygons in different shapes, most of them squeezed.

How can I create one line inside each polygon, along? I have checked it in QGIS but could not find a way to do it.

I have tried to create a centroid for polygons and from the centroid create a straight line within that polygon as in the attached image.

[image]

Comment: did you try this: [Calculating the longest distance within polygon in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/361539/calculating-the-longest-distance-within-polygon-in-qgis) BERAs Answer contains creating a line layer in the longest distance of the polygon (see second part of BERAs answer)

Comment: As long as possible but always inside?